# Animated view transitions. How to defer removing or inserting element?

Tags: ember.js

I try to make some animated transitions between connecting different outlets. I know there are methods like `willInsertElement` , `didInsertElement` or `willDestroyElement` on View class which you can override, but you can not defer appending or especially removing an element. I was trying to override other methods but view class is to complicated to understand how it works. I came up with some idea:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/robak86/mu9XV/)

```
    AnimationHelper = Ember.Object.extend({
        isPreviousViewFadedOut:false,
        nextViewToFadeIn:null,
        triggerManually: true,
        setNextViewToFadeIn:function (view) {
            if (this.nextViewToFadeIn) {
                if (this.hasObserverFor('isPreviousViewFadedOut')) {
                    this.removeObserver('isPreviousViewFadedOut', this.nextViewToFadeIn, 'fadeInCallback');
                }
            }
            this.nextViewToFadeIn = view;
            this.addObserver('isPreviousViewFadedOut', this.nextViewToFadeIn, 'fadeInCallback');
        }
    });

    AnimatedView = Ember.View.extend({
        didInsertElement:function () {
            this.$().hide();

            if (AnimatedView.aHelper.get('triggerManually')) {
                AnimatedView.aHelper.set('isPreviousViewFadedOut', true);
                this.fadeInCallback();

                //next time we don't want call fadeInCallback manually
                AnimatedView.aHelper.set('triggerManually', false);
            } else {
                AnimatedView.aHelper.setNextViewToFadeIn(this);
            }
        },

        fadeInCallback:function () {
            if (AnimatedView.aHelper.get('isPreviousViewFadedOut')) {
                this.$().fadeIn(1000);
            }
        },

        willDestroyElement:function () {
            AnimatedView.aHelper.set('isPreviousViewFadedOut', false);
            var clone = this.$().clone();
            this.$().replaceWith(clone);

            var that = this;
            clone.fadeOut(1000, function () {
                $(this).remove();
                if (AnimatedView.aHelper.nextViewToFadeIn == that) {
                    AnimatedView.aHelper.removeObserver('isPreviousViewFadedOut',
                        AnimatedView.aHelper.nextViewToFadeIn, 'fadeInCallback');
                } else {
                    AnimatedView.aHelper.set('isPreviousViewFadedOut', true);
                }
            });
        }
    })

    AnimatedView.reopenClass({
        aHelper:new AnimationHelper()
    })
```

It seems to work fine, but this is probably very bad design. Is there any better way to achieve similar effect? or maybe I'm completely wrong and should look at problem from very different perspective? for example do animations inside View which wraps another View etc.?

Comment: You may find this presentation helpful: https://speakerdeck.com/machty/ember-meetup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also these might help a lot:

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/animation-support-in-ember-1-1/1977

https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet

If you could select an answer that'd be really helpful to reducing the number of unanswered Stack Overflow questions on Ember.

Answer (score 0):

There was a pull request a little while back that was merged into master that added some extra hooks to `Em.ContainerView` that would have allowed an async transitionary period between two views in an outlet, but that change was reverted soon after due to it causing errors and not really being a well-discussed approach for allowing for transitions between two outlet views.

The Ember core team's lately been focusing on making it really easy to tie your application's views to the Router by way of one-view-at-a-time outlets, and such a system doesn't really make it easy to do what you're trying to do. Almost certainly, if those transitions are valuable to you, you'll want to not use outlets at all and instead manually create/append/animate the views yourself as you enter and exit states. Perhaps Ember core will take another look at this problem at some point, but I wouldn't expect it before the upcoming v 1.0 release.

I do believe that the recently published Yapp app built in Ember took the approach of having a state for every single transition between every "landing" state, and didn't make use of `outlet`s at all. The app's built by some smart people and is doing quite well, so it definitely seems like advice to stand by.